# ORM: JSON instead of LOB in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, orm

Is there a way of serializing arrays or maps as JSONs instead of LOB in Hibernate? Is there a way how to do it with annotations? This way the columns might be human readable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two options:

- make the column `private String content`, and set JSON inside it: `entity.setContent(toJson(content))`. You can use GSON or Jackson for to `toJson` method.
- use a [custom hibernate `@Type`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types), and implement it to serialize a field to JSON.